# Create a Set of String with Column Header as string title and string value as row 0 value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, loops, dataset

I have column 1 column 2 and column 3. At row 0 for each of these i have Values 1,2,3 respectively.

How can I build a loop that will set

```
string column 1 = 1
string column 2 = 2
string column 3 = 3
```

so that the strings name is the column headers and the value of the string is the value in row 0 of that column.

This needs to be done for about 150+ columns and I am looking to avoid individually typing out.

Columns are in a table called "ShipmentInfo"

Comment: what control are you using to make these columns?  Why can't you just loop through the column array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for (int index = 0; index < DT.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    foreach (DataColumn DC in DT.Columns)
    {
        DT.Rows[index][DC] = index;
    }
}
```

Here DT is DataTable object.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have a filled table I am looking to create strings based on the information in my table.